# Slim Framework: How to catch multiple fully OPTIONAL routes?

Tags: php, routes, arguments, slim, option-type

### What i already have

Main thing is that, my base route is already an Optional route. Which is, like:

```
$app->get('/{id}', function(...){
    if ( $args['id'] ) {
        /**
         * Show Item Details
         */
    } else {
        /**
         * Redirects to Home
         */
    }
});
```

That's perfectly working. And that translates to:

> www.example.com/DRX1487

### What i want to achieve

Now what i want is something like:

> www.example.com/DRX1487/reorder
>
> www.example.com/DRX1487/cancel

I tried:

```
$app->get('/{id}/{action}', function(...){...});

$app->get('/:id/:action', function(...){...});
```

Both doesn't work.

How do i achieve this please? All the example i've found (for Optional Routing) are all based on the static base route first. But my base route is already an Optional Route.

Please kindly advise.

Comment: Why not create separate routes? For home `$app->get('/', HomeController::class);`, for item detail  `$app->get('/{id}', ItemDetailController::class);` , for item reorder `$app->get('/{id}/reorder', ItemDetailReorderController::class);`, `$app->get('/{id}/cancel', ItemDetailCancelController::class);`

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara, thanks for suggestion. I got your point. But if i do that, it means the Action Routes (`/reorder` or `/cancel`) are out of the `/{id}`. Which means i cannot detect if the `/{id}/` is valid id or not. Meaning, i cannot leverage on the existing `/{id}` id checking steps. It won't redirect back to `Home` if the `/{id}` is not existed.

Comment: you can always refactor id checking into separate class which then can be injected into each of class that requires it.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara, well, looks like thats the way to go. But, out of curiosity, isn't that something technically possible to achieve.. if its' a desperate need?

Comment: Yes it is possible you just need to check the availability of `$args['action']`. I personally, like more cleaner approach by separating each routes into one separate controller class.

Comment: Could you please post those as the Answer pls? So that i can accept. Please include both approaches if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With separate routes, each codes that handle action can be simple and lean in size. For example.

```
 $app->get('/', HomeController::class); 
 $app->get('/{id}', ItemDetailController::class);
 $app->get('/{id}/reorder', ItemDetailReorderController::class);
 $app->get('/{id}/cancel', ItemDetailCancelController::class);
```

Controller for homepage

```
class HomeController 
{
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $args)
    {  
        //do something   
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Base controller for item-related thing

```
abstract class BaseItemDetailController 
{
     protected function isValidId($id)
     {
          //do validation of id here
     }

     abstract public function __invoke($request, $response, $args);
}
```

Controller dthat display item detail

```
class ItemDetailController extends BaseItemDetailController
{
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $args)
    {  
        $id = $args['id'];
        if ($this->isValidId($id)) {
            //do something to display item detail
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Controller for reorder item

```
class ItemDetailReorderController extends BaseItemDetailController
{
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $args)
    {  
        $id = $args['id'];
        if ($this->isValidId($id)) {
            //do something to reorder item
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Controller that handle cancelling item

```
class ItemDetailCancelController extends BaseItemDetailController
{
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $args)
    {  
        $id = $args['id'];
        if ($this->isValidId($id)) {
            //do something to cancel item ordered
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Optional parameter is defined using bracket. With your initial approach, things can get convoluted very easily, avoid this following code if you can.

```
$app->get('/[{id}[/{action}]]', function(...) {
     if (isset($args['id'])) {
          if (isValid($args['id'])) {
             if (isset($args['action'])) {
                 if ($args['action'] === 'reorder') {
                     //do item reorder
                     return $response;
                 }
                 if ($args['action'] === 'cancel') {
                     //do item cancel
                     return $response;
                 }   
                 //do something (display item detail?)
                 return $response;
             } else {
                 //show item detail
             }
          }
     } else {
          /**
          * Redirects to Home
          */
     }
});
```